# Unable to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: c++, cmake

Here is my CMakeLists file:

```
set(LibName "VibraniumEngine")
set(RAYLIB_VERSION 4.2.0)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/dep/raylib/lib")
find_package(raylib)

if(NOT raylib)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "RayLib library not found")
else()
    message( "RayLib library found!")
endif()
```

This is the files/folders structure of the prebuilt raylib library I have downloaded and trying to add as dependency:

[image]

As you can see I am doing `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/dep/raylib/lib")` giving exact directory where the raylib can be found.

However I still receive this error:

```
CMake Warning at Source/VibraniumEngine/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findraylib.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "raylib", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "raylib" with any
  of the following names:

    raylibConfig.cmake
    raylib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "raylib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "raylib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "raylib"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


CMake Error at Source/VibraniumEngine/CMakeLists.txt:7 (message):
  RayLib library not found
```

Any idea why and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you mean to use an abolute path here: `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/dep/raylib/lib")`? Or did you mean to use something more like `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${<PROJECT_NAME>_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/raylib/lib")`? [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html) or [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html)?

Comment: @user the whole path is something like this `/Project/dep/raylib/lib/` You can see it in the question

Comment: What is actually do you have under `dep/raylib` subdirectory? Directories `include` and `lib` suggests that do you have **installation** there, but the file `CMakeLists.txt`, but file `CMakeLists.txt` suggests that you have **sources** there... In any case, do you ever have one of files noted by CMake - `raylibConfig.cmake` or `raylib-config.cmake`? If you have no of these files, then `find_package` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're (unintentionally) using an absolute path that doesn't exist.

You do `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/dep/raylib/lib")`, which is how you write absolute paths (except if you're on windows). You probably meant to use something more like `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${<PROJECT_NAME>_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/raylib/lib")` ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html)) or `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/raylib/lib")` ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html)). Take your pick and adjust as necessary. Your screenshot and CMakeLists.txt snippet don't show enough context to give you a 100% complete answer.

Comment: I have updated the question with full path screenshot.  I also tried with this `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/raylib/lib")` Which to test I did this `message("PREFIX PATH")
message(${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})` which gives output `/home/myUser/VibraniumCore/dep/raylib/lib` which is exactly the full path. However still I see the error `RayLib library not found` Any idea ?

Comment: @Venelin `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` will only be right if your project never gets add_subdirectoried into another project. Well... does that path actually contain a find config file? How would I know? Your question post is just a screenshot and that folder is collapsed in the screenshot. Hold on- just let me turn on my x-ray goggles or teleport to your location so I can find out. (or you could edit your question)

Answer (score -2):

Think the problem is not with the path itself, but rather with "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "raylib".

See: https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/cmake

Comment: what do you mean ?